# Will apache common-io package buffer data before real IO operations?

Tags: java, apache, file-io, fileutils

I want to use apache common-io package, but I am not sure whether there are any buffer strategies in the write/read functions.
For example, in FileUtil class there are functions like

```
    static void write(File file, CharSequence data);
```

If every call to these functions follows open->read/write->close, the efficiency will be low. I believe there must be some buffering strategies, right?

cheng

Comment: It's open-source, you know - just look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't cache the open files or you might risk running out of file handles, or failing to rename/delete files because they are open.

It uses some buffering but when write() returns you can expect the file to be closed.